# Looser condition for regularity for Neumann problems

Tags: elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, regularity

If $u(x) = g(|x|)$ is a rotationally symmetric function in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ then
$$\Delta u = g''(|x|) + n |x|^{-1} g'(|x|).$$

Let's say we are studying rotationally symmetric solutions to parabolic equation: perhaps $(\partial_t - \Delta) u = A(|x|, u)$.   We end up studying
\begin{equation}
(\partial_t - \partial_r^2) g 
= n r^{-1}\partial_r g + A(r, g). \label{test}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
For differentiability of $u$ we will have a a Neumann boundary condition for $g$ at $r=0$.

Now, if we have some standard regularity theorem valid in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ we can apply it to $u$ to learn something about $g$.  For instance, if $A$ is a $C^{\infty}_{loc}$ function of $g$ and we have an a priori bound $c < g < C$, then we get interior estimates for derivatives of $g$.  This is despite the apparently bad coefficient $r^{-1}$ on $\partial_r$ in \eqref{test}.

I'd like to know if that is clear from \eqref{test} directly.  In my situation I have a larger system, and when deriving equations for various quantities derived from the system I end up with coefficients like $n + 4$ on $r^{-1}\partial_r g$.  Ideally, I would not like to look silly for saying "consider this function rotated in $\mathbb{R}^{n+5}$" if there is a standard way to deal with regularity for \eqref{test}.  Furthermore, that trick would not work for
$$(\partial_t - \partial_r^2)g = \alpha r^{-1}\partial_r g + A(r, g)\label{alpha}\tag{2}$$
if $\alpha$ is not a natural number.

To have a concrete question,

> Suppose $A$ is smooth, $\alpha \geq 0$, and $g$ satisfies \eqref{alpha}  with a bound $|g| < C$ for $(r,t) \in [0, 1] \times [0,1]$.  Is there a $C'(A, \alpha)$ such that $|\partial_r g| < C'$ for $(r,t) \in [0, 1/2] \times [1/2, 1]$?

Note that for $A = 0$ the equation has a solution
$$g = \frac{1}{-\alpha + 1}r^{-\alpha + 1}.$$
If $\alpha < 0$ is not an integer, then this satisfies the Neumann condition but is not smooth.  That is why I ask for $\alpha > 0$.

Ideally Id like an answer that comes from a general principle that lets us see the level of regularity we should expect.

Comment: If $g$ is a solution of (2) it can depend on both $(x,t)$? If so what is $g'$?

Comment: I meant $\partial_r g $- changed.